# <picture> element does not responds well on a Safari web browser

Tags: html

I used a `<picture>` element to make the image responsive based on the screen sizes. It works fine on most of the web browsers except **Safari**. With **Safari** web browser I have to refresh the page each time to see the expected results.

To fix this issue, I added **polyfill** from the following site and followed the instructions: http://scottjehl.github.io/picturefill/ but it didn't resolve the issue.

Any help regarding this issue would be greatly appreciated!

Here's the markup of `<picture>` element:

```html
<picture>
  <source media="(min-width: 600px)" srcset="images/image-lrg.jpg" />
  <img src="images/image-smll.jpg" alt="image of laptop" />
</picture>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<picture>
   <source media="(min-width: 600px)" srcset="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_lights.jpg" />
   <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_5terre.jpg" alt="Cinque Terre" />
</picture>
```

**Read about URL:** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_is_a_URL

**Read about Browser compatibility - `<picture>`:** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/picture#browser_compatibility